# How can I call the method that is in my Hub from my controller on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, signalr

I'm using SignalR and I my hub is on a folder called Hubs. I need to call the method that's in my Hub "PostMarker()" on my controller. So, everytime something is posted, the SignalR updates all windows open. How should I do that?

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostOcorrencias([FromBody] Ocorrencias ocorrencia, IFormFile UploadImag)
    { 

        ocorrencia.DataOcorrencia = DateTime.Now;

        //processar a fotografia
        //ocorrencia.Fotografia = "(nome fotografia)";
        string caminho = "";


        if (UploadImag == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            if (UploadImag.ContentType == "imagens/jpg" ||
                UploadImag.ContentType == "imagens/png")
            {
                string extensao = Path.GetExtension(UploadImag.FileName).ToLower();
                Guid g;
                g = Guid.NewGuid();
                string nome = g.ToString() + extensao;
                caminho = Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath,"imagens", nome);
                ocorrencia.Fotografia = nome;
                // Cria o ficheiro no sistema
                using (var stream = new FileStream(caminho, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await UploadImag.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

            }
        }

            _context.Ocorrencias.Add(ocorrencia);
           //CALL HUB METHOD PostMarker()
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetOcorrencias", new { id = ocorrencia.Id }, ocorrencia);
    }
```

Here is my Hub:

```
  public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public async Task PostMarker()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("RedesignMap");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at injecting IHubContext<MyHub> into your controller? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: When I add thid part on my controller "_hubContext = hubContext;" it doesn't recognize _hubContext. It says that a readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)

Comment: The first code snippet on the page I linked to (1) defines the readonly field and also (2) assigns it in the controller's constructor. Have you added step (2) to your code?

Comment: Are talking about this part? "app.Use(async (context, next){...});"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SignalR `IHubContext` provides a means of sending messages to your clients outside of a Hub instance. The sample at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1 provides an example. Using the code there as a starting point, you can:

Inject the `IHubContext` into your controller, assuming that it is named `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

Use the hub context in your `PostOcorrencias` controller action:

```
...
_context.Ocorrencias.Add(ocorrencia);
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("RedesignMap");
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
...
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you